# Debugging T4 Template VS2013

Tags: t4

I am trying to debug T4 template in Visual Studio 2013. But I don't see "Debug T4 Template" option when I right click on my .tt file in solution explorer.
What do I need to do to be able to see that option and to successfully debug the template?

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes you have to wait for the Error List to Load till you can Debug T4.